# Search for string value without diacritics

Tags: arangodb, aql

Is it possible in AQL to search for document field string value without diacritics, e.g. through `CONTAINS` or `LIKE` functions? For example string value stored in database has value `tomáš` and I want to find it through value `tomas`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid, this is not possible at the moment. There is no built-in diacritics-insensitive search in those functions.

Though, a few options would be:

- Additionally store a non-diacritics-version of the search-word in the document, so that you can query it that way.
- Write a custom function in which you would implement that kind of functionality. Though, I suspect that this would have a negative impact on performance. See the docs on that: https://www.arangodb.org/manuals/current/ExtendingAql.html
- Open a feature-request-issue to implement this kind of functionality in ArangoDB. Who knows, maybe it gets implemented? (https://github.com/triAGENS/ArangoDB/issues)

Comment: BTW, out of curiosity I looked around, and found this nice converter written in Javascript. 

It seems to have a rather rich map of letters with diacritics to latin ones.

See: http://semplicewebsites.com/removing-accents-javascript